# Chose position on x-axis for boxes in boxplot using python

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I would like to show my data as a boxplot where each box is at a specific distance on the x-axis. So ideally like figure 1 but instead of a scatter plot a box plot diagram. [Scatter plot where x-axis is distances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flTXc.png)

At the moment I have gotten this far. I get the result as in figure 2 [Boxplot diagram from logger data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BST0.png)

```
sp_boxplot = 20
dist =  [139, 101, 52.5, 210, 91, 45.5]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))   

boxplt = df_lags_from_stormevents.boxplot(column = ['Logger 7', 'Logger 4', 'Logger 6', 'Logger 3', 'Logger 2', 'Logger 5'], 
                                          showfliers=False,grid = False,figsize = (12,10))   

ax1.boxplot(df_lags_from_stormevents, positions = sorted(dist), notch=True)

    
boxplt.set_xlabel('Distance from coast', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 10)
boxplt.set_ylabel('Delay at best correlation [hours]', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 10)
boxplt.set_xlim([0,7])
boxplt.set_ylim([0,50])
boxplt.legend(loc = 'lower right', fontsize = 12)
boxplt.text(0.05, 0.75, lin_func_b_median +  '\n' + r'( r$^{2}$ = ' + (str(round(r2_lin_b,3))) + ')', 
             transform = boxplt.transAxes,  fontsize = 12, bbox=dict(facecolor='w', edgecolor = 'k'))
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the `positions=sorted(dist)` argument to the first call of the `boxplot` method instead?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but then it doesn't plot any thing and doesn't come with an error to inform me what the problem is.